# How do I use a phrase query in liferay with stop words

Tags: elasticsearch, search, liferay, liferay-7

I am using Liferay 7.1 together with ElasticSearch and all I want to do is to search for (EXAMPLE): "This is a test".

But in this case "is" and "a" are stop words, they get filtered out, and therefore I do get results that I do not want like : "This test rocks".

I am using a BooleanQuery like this:

```
BooleanQuery keywordQuery = new BooleanQueryImpl();
keywordQuery.addTerms(KEYWORDS, keyword, false);
```

Keyword in this case is "this is a test".

Can anyone tell me how to make the BooleanQuery not filter out stop words ?

Best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Stop-Words are a concept of the analysis phase when indexing. So your index does not contain "is" and "a". Therefore, there is no param at query time to use stop words.

What you could do, is to use a different search index attribute which contains the full content with stop words. This depends on your configuration, maybe the is already an attribute without stopword, or you need to add one using a Index Post-Proccessor or modify your elastic Mapping Configuration.

Please check your documents structure (e.g. with elastic HQ) to inspect the attributes for stopwords.